# Liferay 6 , Custom Login Page

Tags: liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6  for development , i have developed Liferay6 Struts2 Portlet and deployed .
Using Custom JSPs Hooks , i have overridden  the $PORTAL_ROOT_HOME/html/portlet/login login.jsp and created 
my own jsp page as shown

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Login using jsp</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <H1>LOGIN FORM</H1>
            <form>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td> Username  : </td><td> <input name="username" size=15 type="text" /> </td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> Password  : </td><td> <input name="password" size=15 type="text" /> </td> 
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="login" />
            </form>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

This works fine , the custom jsp  page is being shown up . 
Now please tell upon clicking on the submit button , how can i wrie a java class which validates the credentials aganist database .

Please tell me how can i recieve these values under my class and validate them .

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have got a solution by this time. If not, you can try the following.

I believe you are trying to override the login portlet of liferay. In that case there are 2 ways you can handle this login mechanism.( make sure that the same name is given to input fields as liferay's login page has)

1. Extend the liferay's LoginAction class. You have to write an ext plugin or if you are using 6.0 SP2 or 6.1 you can use a hook to extend LoginAction class. Refere mika's blog http://www.liferay.com/web/mika.koivisto/blog/-/blogs/7132115
2. Write your own class which should implement liferay's Authenticator interface and you have to override 3 methods of Authenticator interface.

For example if you are overriding authenticateByEmailAddress(....), you have to return a SUCCESS(1) or FAILURE(-1). I believe the 2nd and 3rd parameters of the method are user id and password that are entered on the screen. please refer liferay source.

In order to bypass liferay's default authentication mechanism, give the following configuration on the portal-ext.properties auth.pipeline.pre=your.package.your.class

Still liferay check against its own database. To avoid that add following configuration on portal-ext.properties.

auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check=false.

So you have your own custom authentication where you can authenticate against your own database or what ever mechanism you want.

More Details http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Developing+a+Custom+Authentication+System

Hope this helps